# Cloning HDD to a Larger HDD

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, backup, clone

I’m trying to clone a 1TB HDD to a 2TB HDD and so far it’s been 15 hours. Am I doing anything wrong?

I first used [Macrium](https://www.macrium.com) and that took 3 hours but resulted in a new disk with the exact same order of partitions with a very large unallocated space at the end. I tried to use [MiniTool](https://www.minitool.com) to move the unallocated space to append to C drive but it would not move.

I am currently using [MiniTool](https://www.minitool.com) to clone the disk. This time it allowed me to shuffle the order of the partitions before the clone. This is where I am at now, it having been what seems an inordinate number of hours. 15 so far.

I suspect the type of partitions may be causing the problem. The Linux ones are in the middle of C dirive and the unallocated space. They may be blocking the movement of C and the unallocated space. The partitions are in order:

- SYSTEM
- C drive ntfs
- Ext4 Linux
- Unallocated Linux swap
- D Recovery ntfs
- E HP_Tools fat32

(Unallocated space after clone)

Trying to change the order to make the Unalloced appear after C drive is not possible before or after clone except only with MiniTool before the cloning operation.

Sometimes the software will change the sizes of the existing partitions in the new clone. I altered them back to their original size with the exception of the new C drive which becomes bigger.

Comment: I would use sector-by-sector clone, then boot Linux and use `gparted` to manipulate the partitions and free space on the cloned disc. Alternatively, in Windows make a new partition in the free space and migrate the data directories (such as `C:\Users`) there.

Comment: https://clonezilla.org/ can do automatic size adjustment as well can run in rescue mode when source drive has bad sectors. You can also say to clonezilla to not adjust partitions but do it later with `gparted`

Comment: It finished. The partitions are in correct order. However a few of the smaller partitions have slightly larger sizes. I’d like to pare them down to their previous levels.  GParted does not recognize the partitions just created. It reported the total disk size as being unallocated. I think the drive is mounted. Ironically some of the copied partitions can be browsed using the file manager.

Answer (score 0):

Right click partition E in MiniTool Partition Wizard, change the location between this partition and the Unallocated space with Move/Resize feature. Use the same method to move the unallocated space to be after Linux Swap. 
Then, you need to use Linux partition tool like Gparted to move the unallocated space to be after partition C.
At last, go to Windows Disk Management and take the un allocated space to extend partition C.