# What happens to empty space when cloning to a larger disk?

Tags: ssd, disk-cloning, macrium

I am trying to learn about cloning a small SSD to a larger SSD using Macrium. My OS (Windows 10) is installed on a 120 GB SSD but I need to clone the OS to a 500 GB SSD and then insert the new SSD into the laptop. I'm doing this because there are some programs I need which take up a lot of space when installed. I have all the hardware so I'm ready to go. However, I'm having trouble understanding the process. The process is described on the Macrium website [here](https://knowledgebase.macrium.com/display/KNOW72/Cloning+a+disk), but it looks like that process results in unused space. I am trying to avoid having a large unallocated space as happened to [this user](https://superuser.com/questions/1342335/cloning-hdd-to-a-larger-hdd).

This is what the program is showing me:

[image]

There should be around 357 GB of free space after cloning, but is that space still part of the C drive? When programs are installed on the C drive will they be able to use that space? Or is it just extra space for non-installed files like videos or pictures? How can I make sure that the new C drive will use that extra space for large program installations?

*EDIT:
I've gotten this far - will this work?*

[image]

Comment: I would caution you from cloning a BitLocker protected drive.  You should disable BitLocker protection, clone the drive, then simply enable it on the new drive.  You should also have the BitLocker recovery key ready to be used if you don't do this.  "but is that space still part of the C drive?" - It will be unallocated space at the end of the disk.  You will be unable to extend your system disk using that unallocated space since it's at the end of the disk (second screenshot).

Comment: Thanks for the advice. So, disable Bitlocker in the BIOS? Then clone and I should be able to enable it again on the cloned drive?

Comment: You disable BitLocker protection within Windows.  If you wipe TPM like I suspect you might be asking about then your only recourse would be that BitLocker recovery key.

Comment: TPM? Yes I will make sure to keep the recovery keys safe and ready to use.

Comment: You should research if you are using the TPM installed in your machine or no to enable BitLocker protection. How you do that is well documented.

Comment: Yes laptop uses TPM. Should I turn off all encryption before cloning?