# What issues should I anticipate when cloning encrypted disks?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ssd, encryption, clone

This question is related to my other questions about cloning [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1609353/what-happens-to-empty-space-when-cloning-to-a-larger-disk), but I am cloning my OS from a small SSD to a larger SSD. It's a DELL laptop with Windows 10 and it has core isolation, TPM, and Secure Boot as security. If I clone the disk, I assume I should turn off all encryption beforehand. But will I be able to turn it back on after I install the cloned disk? Will the encryption detect some difference and fail to boot? What issues do I need to be aware of?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the cloning was done right, the new system disk is autonomous and does not know
about the history of the previous disk.

Unencrypting before cloning is the right way to go. Afterward, you may encrypt
the new disk.

Just to warn that encrypting is a serious operation that requires careful
backups. I have encountered many posts here from users whose encryption was broken
and who lost all their data.

Comment: In my case I will have the original SSD as a backup, but I will also make cloud backups to be extra safe. As for re-encrypting the new drive, the only option I see in Windows 10 is Device Security/Turn on encryption. What is the serious operation that you are referring to?

Comment: Any operation that affects all the data on the disk is serious, because if it is interrupted then the disk might become unusable.

Comment: The destination disk is what you mean, I assume?

Comment: All disks: encryption, decryption, defragmenting, partition editing, Windows Update and more. All such operations are dangerous if interrupted or failed for any reason.

Comment: I see. Thank you for the sensible advice.

Comment: Question: You said "If the cloning was done right, the new system disk is autonomous and does not know about the history of the previous disk.". In that case, why do I need to turn off encryption beforehand? Just trying to clarify in my head.

Comment: I meant cloning after turning off encryption. This too-strong wording of mine was because I have encountered here quite a few posts where the cloning was done using the wrong tools and the result was data lose or a weird disk that needed saving. In your case, at least you will have the old disk as a safe backup.

Comment: When you say "wrong tools", what do you recommend as the correct tools to clone a disk in that case? What is your recommended procedure?

Comment: The tool I use most is [AOMEI Backupper](https://www.ubackup.com/free-backup-software.html), but there are others. Avoid Linux-based utilities such as Clonezilla that may not perfectly understand NTFS.

Comment: I was planning to use Macrium Reflect. Do you know this one?

Comment: It's very well known and is Windows specific, so no problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is an update for anyone else doing this process:

I fully decrypted the disk - it took around 16 hours to decrypt.
I tried to use Macrium to clone the disk but I encountered errors that I wasn't able to solve using their support or forums. I tried Acronis True Image but had problems with that too. I switched to AOMEI Backupper and had to buy the full version to be able to adjust the partition sizes. Even then I wasn't able to fully customize the partition sizes, but it was the only program that seemed to work. I was able to clone the disk with AOMEI. I inserted the new SSD into my laptop and it works. I am now re-encrypting the disk - no issues.

In summary, decrypting takes a very long time and AOMEI was the only program that worked for the cloning process.

Comment: That information contradicts the other answer I received.